# 3ds max layout is broken and texts are cut-off?

Tags: fonts, layout, 3ds-max

I installed 3ds max 2020.3.2x64 on Windows 10 and the texts on the side are cut-off. I assume it might be a windows bug? any idea how to fix this? I have tried installing different versions and changing resolutions, IDP, and text scales on my windows but the issue still persists.

[image: this is an image of how the texts look inside the application]